# calculating velocity

Tags: android, scroll, surfaceview, glsurfaceview, smooth-scrolling

Im trying to implement inertial scrolling in my GLSurfaceView and to do that i need to figure out how to calculate velocity, but im not sure how to do so. the translation is stored in a matrix, and it is calculated by the line of code below.

```
matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,event.getY() - start.y);
```

Comment: What alternative physics is this?  I see changes in x- and y-position, but no mention of time.  Is there an implicit time step somewhere else in the code?

Comment: no there isn't, the only code that contributes to the scrolling is shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Scroller`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) and [`VelocityTracker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html) classes. Together they are used to implement fling behavior in the standard framework widgets. Use these and your app will always match the native feel of the device.